# How to minimize the python3.5.2 interpreter for arm linux?

Tags: python-3.x, linux, arm, cross-compiling, embedded-linux

My company is going to cross complied python3.5.2 interpreter on Arm Linux, the board is Lichee Pi Nano(The SoC is Allwinner f1c100s, there is a 16MB SPI Flash on the board).

I tried cross complied the python3.5.2 source code with openssl and zlib, the "install" folder I complied is about 137MB, too much bigger than the flash size.

Is anyone has any clue about how to minimize python source code?

Thanks !!!

Comment: Look at the section sizes with readelf, etc.  Extab, debug, etc are not needed.  3Mb should be appropriate.  Afair ssl was 100k, zlib is even smaller.

Comment: Compile options and libc can affect binary sizes.

Comment: https://micropython.org/, https://github.com/micropython/micropython  The SQL requirement is quite huge and will blow away your 16MB foot print.  I think Rust and forth would be better languages to look at, but it all depends on your companies skill set.  micropython is  probably best if you must go this route.  Also, my recollection of OpenSSL is wrong.  It was possible to use 1MB at one point (0.9.7 type).  However, more recent versions seem much bigger.  There are alternative frameworks that aim to minimize binary; trading performance.